# How to get variable value from html into views.py in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

**html code:**

```
{% for data in top_100_active_webshells_tuple %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ data.0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.1 }}</td>       
    <td>{{ data.2 }}</td>
    <td><form action="/my_image/" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <input id ="my_input" type="submit" class="btn" name="{{ data.3 }}" value="image" style="background:white;color:black;border:3px solid grey"/>
</form>
     </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py function:**

```
def my_image(request):

    if "data.3" in request.GET:
        address=request.GET["data.3"]
        resp="address is "+address
        return HttpResponse(resp)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("error here")
```

**Question:**
 Question is that i can't get value stored in variable "data.3 "in the function named
 
*def my_image(request)*

And else statement is printed when i click input button,how to fix it and get variable value in *views.py*

Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: The name of the field is the *value* of whatever `data.3` is in each iteration. Which is a very odd thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will **get the value of `data.3` and not `data.3` as a key** in the request data.

Also, you will receive the data in `request.POST` and not `request.GET` as form method is `POST`.

```
def my_image(request):

    if <value_of_data.3> in request.POST:
        address=request.POST[<value_of_data.3>]
        resp="address is "+address
        return HttpResponse(resp)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("error here")
```

But, as you are iterating and the value  of `data.3` might change in different requests, you won't be able to get your view to work correctly everytime as intended using the above logic.